# How to view floating point numbers in Eclipse Memory view?

Tags: debugging, floating-point, eclipse-cdt

In Eclipse CDT we have the Memory view which allows examining the contents of the memory. However, it seems like the available numeric formats are limited to integral types. Is there a way to view floating point numbers in the Memory view?

In the Expression view I can do `*((float *) (some-address))` to view the contents as float, but this is good only for a few memory locations, and I need to view arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "Variables" view? Also check if you have pretty printing enabled. See http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_can_I_inspect_the_contents_of_STL_containers.3F